# Android update SQLite with GSON response ... how should I parse nested JSON?

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist, gson

I have tried to figure this out on my own...  starting with two excellent tutorials on GSON parsing  from [High-Speed Blog](http://blog.brianbuikema.com/2010/04/android-how-to-deserialize-both-xml-and-json/) and [Java Code Geeks](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html).  Several [answers] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763937/gson-and-deserializing-an-array-of-objects-with-arrays-in-it/6300251#6300251) on stackoverflow are relevant, but I need more help than a screendump.  I want to update my SQLite database from the following JSON response:

```
            {
                "Field": "13",
                "Plants": [
                    {
                        "PlantID": 123,
                        "PlotID": 321,
                        "Row": 1,
                        "Post": 1,
                        "Position": 1,
                        "PlotName": "Sunnyside",
                        "Breed": "Daisy"
                    },
                    {
                        "PlantID": 149,
                        "PlotID": 348,
                        "Row": 1,
                        "Post": 20,
                        "Position": 1,
                        "PlotName": "Waterside",
                        "Breed": "Iris"
                    }
                ]
            }
```

my root class (jsonPlots) and 'nested' class (Plants) are as follows:

```
    public class jsonPlots {
      @SerializedName("Field")
        public String mFieldId;
      public ArrayList<Plants> PlantArray;
    }
    public class Plants {
        @SerializedName("PlantID")
        public int jPlantID;

        @SerializedName("PlotID")
        public int jPlotID;

        @SerializedName("Row")
        public int jRow; 

        @SerializedName("Post")
        public int jPost;

        @SerializedName("Position")
        public int jPosition;

        @SerializedName("PlotName")
        public String jPlotName;

        @SerializedName("Breed")
        public String jBreed;

    }
```

I have verified that I am getting a valid response using the following snippet:

```
    public void getJsonData() {
      InputStream source = retrieveStream(url);     
      Gson gson = new Gson();      
      Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(source);      
      jsonPlots response = gson.fromJson(reader, jsonPlots.class);
      Toast.makeText(this, response.mFieldId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  // this works
    ArrayList<Plants> results = response.PlantArray;

    if(results.isEmpty()) { ///    null pointer exception here
      Toast.makeText(this, "no data to update", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    else {
        for (Plants result : results) {
              try {
                  Toast.makeText(this, result.jBreed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  //  replace with SQLite update
                  Toast.makeText(this, result.jPlotName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
              finally {
                  Toast.makeText(this, "failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }
    }
}  // getJsonData
```

The first Toast (mFieldID) works.  It crashes at **if(results.isEmpty())** with a null pointer exception as noted.   Is my ArrayList not populating ?   I would like a code suggestion on how to sequence through this nested array... so that I can systematically update my SQLite database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gson doesn't know that you want to bind the `jsonPlots.PlantArray` attribute to the `"Plants"` JSON element, because the names don't match and there isn't any configuration information (e.g., `@SerializedName("Plants")`) to otherwise let Gson know to bind them.

Comment: bruce Thanks for the observation.   I'm sorry, but I don't know how implement what you are talking about... which is why I'm asking the question.  Would you be kind enough to provide a suggestion / correction to the code ?

Comment: bruce was correct.  I changed the 'root' class (jsonPlots) as follows:  public class jsonPlots {
        @SerializedName("Field")
         public String mFieldId;
       @SerializedName("Plants")
       public ArrayList<Plants> PlantArray;
        }