# Gson Array of Array Deserialization

Tags: android, json, arraylist, gson, json-deserialization

I've the following JSON structure:

```
[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "subcategories": [
   {
    "id": 2,
    "subcategories": [
    ]
   },
   {
    "id": 3,
    "subcategories": [
    ]
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "id": 4,
  "subcategories": [
   {
    "id": 5,
    subcategories: [
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

The model class for a Category (some fields like title are omitted for simplicity),
for reflecting JSON structure:

```
public class Category {
    int id = 0;
    ArrayList<Category> subCategories = null;
}
```

I'm trying to parse that with Gson library (2.2.4), having hard times deserializing inner array to arraylist:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Category>>(){}.getType();
ArrayList categories = gson.fromJson(json, collectionType);
```

Category.subCategories is always null.

Comment: Have you looked here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763937/gson-and-deserializing-an-array-of-objects-with-arrays-in-it?rq=1

Comment: Ok, that works...I was missing Array to ArrayList conversion.

Comment: Great! Please answer question and accept your answeryourself so that it is marked `answered`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
gson.fromJson(json, Category[].class)
```

worked good for me. If you want an ArrayList instead of an Array:

```
new ArrayList<Category>(Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(json, Category[].class)));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
public class Category {
    int id = 0;
    ArrayList<Category> subCategories = new ArrayList<Category>()
}
```