# Deserialize array of integers using gson

Tags: java, android, json

this must be a stupid question, but how to deserialize this? (using Gson)

```
{"Requisitions":[129,127,124,46,40,39,38,37,36,35,34,33]}
```

Comment: Have you tried searching "How to deserialize JSON Array using GSON" ?

Comment: yep, but unsuccessfully

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188364/gson-array-of-array-deserialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class RequisitionsClass {
    int[] Requisitions;
}    

RequisitionsClass requisition = new Gson().fromJson(json, RequisitionsClass.class);
```

then you can access the array like this:

```
requisition.Requisitions[0]
```