# looping over json response in classic asp

Tags: json, rest, vbscript, asp-classic

SO I am making a rest request to the JIRA API and getting a json response that includes all objects.

my request look like this:

```
Set restReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")
restReq.open "GET", "URI",False
restReq.setRequestHeader  "Authorization","Basic{user:Password}"
restReq.setOption SXH_OPTION_IGNORE_SERVER_SSL_CERT_ERROR_FLAGS,SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS
restReq.send("")
'response.write(restReq.responseText)
```

the response.write looks like this (but much longer):

```
[{"self":"https://JIRA:8343/rest/api/2/project/CT","id":"10004","key":"CT","name":"Core Technologies"}},
{"self":"https://JIRA:8343/rest/api/2/project/CTCCG","id":"10006","key":"CTCCG","name":"CT CCG"}}]
```

I would like to be able to loop through the response and use the "id", "key" and "name" in an unordered list.  I can create a ul, but how do I extract the information I need from the json?

Comment: VBScript or JScript ASP3?

Comment: See this question and its first two answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019223/any-good-libraries-for-parsing-json-in-classic-asp?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You check [this question relating to using the Gson library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763937/gson-and-deserializing-an-array-of-objects-with-arrays-in-it).  It is very small, quick and easy to use to convert between JSON to Objects.

```
import java.io.FileReader;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    TypeDTO[] myTypes = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("D:\\temp\\inputjson.txt"), TypeDTO[].class);
    for (int i = 0; i < myTypes.length; ++i)
        System.out.println(myTypes[i].self);
 }

class TypeDTO
{
  String self;
  String id;
  String key;
  String name;
}
}
```

inputjson.txt had

```
[{"self":"https://JIRA:8343/rest/api/2/project/CT","id":"10004","key":"CT","name":"Core Technologies"},
 {"self":"https://JIRA:8343/rest/api/2/project/CTCCG","id":"10006","key":"CTCCG","name":"CT CCG"}]
```

note the absence of addtional `}` when compared to yours at the end of each line.