# JSONArray parse with gson

Tags: java, android, gson

It is working when I am trying to retrieve jsonobject through gson but when I use gson for retrieving jsonArray it's not working. How can I retrieve data from the below jsonArray and display to a listview through GSON?

Can anyone help me?

My jsonArray

```
[
 {
    "node_title": "One Day camp",
    "nid": "202605",
    "Icon Image": {
        "fid": "146",
        "uid": "1",
        "filename": "10483937_741467599279220_8365483080196647009_n.jpg",
        "uri": "public://10483937_741467599279220_8365483080196647009_n.jpg",
        "filemime": "image/jpeg",
    }
 },
 { 
    "node_title": "University of Kerala",
    "nid": "202604",
    "Icon Image": {
        "fid": "145",
        "uid": "1",
        "filename": "careerguru.png",
        "uri": "public://careerguru.png",
        "filemime": "image/png",
    }
 }
]
```

Comment: did you make any attempt ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753719/how-to-parse-json-parsing-using-gson-in-android

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the `,` after  `"filemime": "xxx"`

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I think I misunderstood your question. venkatKA's answer is correct.

Typically you would build an object with the same characteristics as the json you expect to receive. For instance,

```
public class MyJsonObject {

    private String node_title;
    private String nid;

    private static class IconImage {

        private String fid;
        private String uid;
        private String filename;
        private String uri;
        private String filemime;

    }

}
```

You would then loop through that JSONArray serializing them with Gson into an array of MyJsonObject's.

(As for the inner class I know Gson can serialize the inner classes but i'm not 100% sure of the syntax to declare that inner class as your "Icon Image")

My point is, Use Gson to serialize the Json response into objects easily/conveniently. But if you're just trying to grab data from the response use the JSONObject classes.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that the POJO class that you want to store the data is already created, i.e: the single json object in your json array.

Lets assume that this class is Node.java and contains a single Node object.

You can get the list of the Node objects from the json using below code through Gson.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Node>>(){}.getType();
List<Node> posts = (List<Node>) gson.fromJson(jsonOutput, listType);
```

Now, you can use the List and use it for showing the data in the list.

And yes, according to [venkatKA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1657076/venkatka)'s answer the json is also wrong as it has an extra ","

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

```
1.Remove , after the  "filemime": "image/jpeg", json error.

2.Parse Json to Gson

public class Array {
@SerializedName("node_title")
@Expose
private String nodeTitle;
@SerializedName("nid")
@Expose
private String nid;
@SerializedName("Icon Image")
@Expose
private com.example.IconImage IconImage;
public String getNodeTitle() {
return nodeTitle;
}

public String getNid() {
 return nid;
}
}


public class IconImage {

@SerializedName("fid")
@Expose
private String fid;
@SerializedName("uid")
@Expose
private String uid;
@SerializedName("filename")
@Expose
private String filename;
@SerializedName("uri")
@Expose
private String uri;
@SerializedName("filemime")
@Expose
private String filemime;

public String getFid() {
return fid;
}

public String getUid() {
return uid;
}

public String getFilename() {
return filename;
}

public String getUri() {
return uri;
}
public String getFilemime() {
return filemime;
}

I hope it helps you.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an excellent example here: [Gson and deserializing an array of objects with arrays in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763937/gson-and-deserializing-an-array-of-objects-with-arrays-in-it)

So you will want to parse your Json string like this:

```
public class IconImage {
    int fid;
    int uid;
    String filename;
    String uri;
    String filemime;
}

public class Node {
    String node_title;
    int nid;
    @SerializedName("Icon Image") IconImage icon_image;
}

Gson gson = new Gson();
Node[] myNodes = gson.fromJson(yourJsonString, Node[].class);
```