# how to read a JSON file in java and store it in a JSONArray

Tags: java, json

how can i read the json file i have and then save it in a JSONArray?

And by `JSONArray` I mean `org.json.JSONArray`, not the `simple.JSONArray`!

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONArray obj = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader(pathJson));
```

I've tried this but i get an error when I try to use `obj.get()` or `obj.opt()` method which says im not allowed to cast `simpleJSONArray` to `JSONArray`

What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gson and deserializing an array of objects with arrays in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763937/gson-and-deserializing-an-array-of-objects-with-arrays-in-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library. In particular you would use the method `fromJson`.

It returns an array of your object. So, you need to create a Java class that represents your object in json file.