# com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to parse the incoming Json (given below) to Java object using Gson. The Json request seems to be a valid one, but I am getting the following exception while parsing it.

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 5 column 19 path $.metadata.
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:226) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:?]
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:?]
```

Incoming Json request :

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "salesId": "123",
        "promoCode": "2010",
        "items": [
            {
                "0": {
                    "productCode": "1234",
                    "total": 169900
                },
                "1": {
                    "productCode": "4567",
                    "total": 19900
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Parsing logic :

```
protected <T extends GenericModel> Optional<T> convertFromJson(final String json, final Class<T> clazz) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(json)) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
        return Optional.of(new Gson().fromJson(json, clazz));
    }
```

Java class :

```
public class Metadata {
    private String salesId;
    private String promoCode;
    private ArrayList<Object> items = new ArrayList<Object>();

    public String getSalesId() {
        return salesId;
    }

    public void setSalesId(String salesId) {
        this.salesId = salesId;
    }

    public String getPromoCode() {
        return promoCode;
    }

    public void setPromoCode(String promoCode) {
        this.promoCode = promoCode;
    }

    public ArrayList<Object> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<Object> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Metadata{" +
                "salesId=" + getSalesId() +
                "promoCode=" + getPromoCode() +
                "items=" + getItems() +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Please note that Metadata.java is an inner class.

Have been trying to resolve the issue, but no luck. Could anyone let me know how to solve it? TIA.

Comment: There is metadata at the beginning, can you add curly brackets at the beginning and at the end og the string and process that?

Comment: Sorry, the braces were there, I missed it while copying it here. Edited the question with updated json. But getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess the problem is with the `items` object in the json you are trying to deserialize.

In the `Metadata` class `items` is an `ArrayList<Object>` but that doesn't tell gson how to deserialize it.

Instead you should try creating another POJO for `Item` and then making the `items` an `ArrayList<Item>`. Something like this: [Gson and deserializing an array of objects with arrays in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763937/gson-and-deserializing-an-array-of-objects-with-arrays-in-it)

You could check if `items` is the problem by commenting out that attribute and sending in just the `salesId` and `promoCode`.

Comment: I did that. So I created a POJO for Item and made the corresponding changes to Metadata. But still facing the same problem. And yes, I tried to parse the Json request without Item and its working fine. So the problem is definitely with Item, just dont know how to fix it. I am wondering why the exception says "Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY" when I have defined it as ArrayList. I mean, why is it expecting a string?

Answer (score 0):

As your json has all data in `metadata` attribute, I created a new POJO having `metadata` field.

```java
class ParentMetadata {
    private Metadata metadata;
    // getters and setters
}
```

And then parsed json to POJO using below code:

```java
ParentMetadata parentMetadata = new Gson().fromJson(jsonStr, ParentMetadata.class);
```

This works fine for me.

Also, as `items` is of type `ArrayList<Object>`, during debugging I could see `items` are deserialized as List of `LinkedTreeMap`.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue and thought I'l post it here incase someone comes across the same issue. I cleaned the project and rebuild again and it worked fine. The issue was not with the code afterall. I read it on a thread regarding gson libraries and tried it. And it worked for me.